# Magento 2: Removing "You added <Product Name> to your shopping cart" message

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, plugin, messages

In the file:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php
```

There are the lines:

```
$message = __(
  'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
  $product->getName()
);
$this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
```

I'd like to remove this message the proper "Magento way", e.g. not just by commenting it out in the core files.

If I were to do it via a plugin, how would I remove that particular message from the queue?

I have a custom module up-and-running and have written plugins before, so I don't require a detailed answer, just the specifics for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is not the best I think, maybe better would be overwrite controller action. Anyways here the way to do this.

> etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="vendor_checkout_cat_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AfterAddCart" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Observer\AfterAddCart

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;

class AfterAddCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerCart
     */
    private $cart;

    /**
     * @param CustomerCart $cart
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerCart $cart
    ){
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->cart->getQuote()->setHasError(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer did work fine for me, however I did receive a deprecation noticed about `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` so instead I used `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` in exactly the same way, it proved to work just as effectively.