# Remove added to cart message in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to remove the Success message when adding to cart. Right now when you click on the `Add to Cart` button it displays a message of `Successfully added <product> to cart` but I don't want to display this. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This has been answered here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178864/magento-2-removing-you-added-product-name-to-your-shopping-cart-message/294938